# Visual Studio 2015 "Quick Find" goes away when switching tabs (files)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

In the Visual Studio 2015 IDE, QuickFind has changed. While I find it irritating that it only has one arrow and a dropdown for forward/back/all, the biggest problem is that it goes away when I click on a new tab (file).

Old Process:

1. Select a a control from an aspx page
2. Ctrl-F to get it into QuickFind
3. Click on the tab for the aspx.vb page
4. Click the arrow to step through the places that the control is referenced

Current Process:

1. Select the control
2. Ctrl-F to open the QuickFind
3. Click the arrow to “find” the thing I’ve selected (or else it won’t be in the dropdown list later)
4. Click on the tab for the new page
5. Ctrl-F again to open the QuickFind
6. Click the dropdown for find history and select the thing I’m searching for
7. Click the arrow to actually perform the find

Further, QuickFind seems to be missing from Productivity Power Tools 2015.

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

I am using asp.net and vb.

Comment: SO is not for explaining missing features in an application.

Comment: @BlackFrog that might be true but questions about tools used by programmers is on-topic.